# Solve this problem?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Here I have 2 lists, A and B. I am trying to find the connection items of list A got with items of list B.

I know:
b) all the items of A
a) the 1st item of B
b) number range from 0-255

A   - B

0   - 219
50  - 224
100 - 231
200 - 246
255 - 255

I am looking for something like: B = A...

(sorry but tags are most likely not correct)

Comment: Approximately(!), $B= 219+\frac{12}{85}\cdot A$.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: Thanks, I got the same using: 219+(255-219)/255*A... Is it possible to get the exact same result, r.g. if A = 50 224 and not 226?

Comment: In the end the approximate results was ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, this could be almost anything and 
$$B=\begin{cases}219&\text{if }A=0\\
224&\text{if }A=50\\
231&\text{if }A=100\\
246&\text{if }A=200\\
255&\text{if }A=255\\
42&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases} $$
would fit. Of course, one expects something "smoother", and there are still many options, for example a polynomial of degree $4$.
However, one *can* find a function based on a quadratic polynomial (and with a small coefficient before the quadratic term) that fits the given data under rounding:
$$ B = \left\lfloor\frac{3A^2}{20000}+\frac{21A}{200}+219\right\rfloor = 219+\left\lfloor\frac{3A}{200}\cdot \left(7+\frac A{100}\right)\right\rfloor.$$